# Azure Java API - How to get vmss scaling settings json

Tags: java, json, azure, api

I have a virtual machine scale set (vmss) in Azure cloud.
How can I get its scaling settings json though my Java app?

In general I need to get its maximum and minimum instance limits, and its scaling rules.

To define my vmss I use:

```
Azure azure = Azure.configure().authenticate(new File(myAzureCredentialsFilePath)).withDefaultSubscription();
VirtualMachineScaleSet vmss = azure.virtualMachineScaleSets().getById("someId");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Azure-SDK's for Java for querying scale set information.

```
System.out.println("Listing scale set virtual machine instance network interfaces and SSH connection string...");
            for (VirtualMachineScaleSetVM instance : virtualMachineScaleSet.virtualMachines().list()) {
                System.out.println("Scale set virtual machine instance #" + instance.instanceId());
                System.out.println(instance.id());
                PagedList<VirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = instance.listNetworkInterfaces();
                // Pick the first NIC
                VirtualMachineScaleSetNetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.get(0);
                for (VirtualMachineScaleSetNicIPConfiguration ipConfig :networkInterface.ipConfigurations().values()) {
                    if (ipConfig.isPrimary()) {
                        List<LoadBalancerInboundNatRule> natRules = ipConfig.listAssociatedLoadBalancerInboundNatRules();
                        for (LoadBalancerInboundNatRule natRule : natRules) {
                            if (natRule.backendPort() == 22) {
                                System.out.println("SSH connection string: " + userName + "@" + publicIPAddress.fqdn() + ":" + natRule.frontendPort());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

virtualMachineScaleSet.virtualMachines().list() might give you what you are looking for.
```

You can find more samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-java-manage-virtual-machine-scale-sets/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/samples/ManageVirtualMachineScaleSet.java). Hope it helps.